# How to select from drop-down list in selenium c# by specific attribute value?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium2, selenium-webdriver, c#

```
<ul class="options"> 
<li data-raw-value="smt-b1bbdd96-f135-48ae-8744-e920942dd7a3" class="selected" data-sys-status="running">3.   LIELA LEGAL SISTĒMA ( EN - LV )</li>
```

I want to select the specific item with the attribute value in the data-war-value attribute. So far  have just made the way to the section but stopped at the selection.

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseUrl + TextTranslate);
new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("options"))).SelectByText(sysID);
```

When I run the test with this kind of code I get this error :

> Test Outcome: Failed Test Duration:   0:00:08,7050235 Result
>   StackTrace:    at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response
>   errorResponse)    at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String
>   driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)    at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(String mechanism,
>   String value)    at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElementByClassName(String
>   className)    at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.By.<>c__DisplayClass12.b__10(ISearchContext
>   context)    at OpenQA.Selenium.By.FindElement(ISearchContext context) 
>   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(By by)    at
>   FirstUnitTest.LetsMT_Tests.TranslateText() in
>   C:\Users\edgars.karkis.TILDE\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\FirstUnitTest\FirstUnitTest\LetsMT_Tests.cs:line 59
>   Result Message:    Test method FirstUnitTest.LetsMT_Tests.TranslateText
>   threw exception:  OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such
>   element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class
>   name","selector":"options"}   (Session info: chrome=46.0.2490.71)
>   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.20.353145
>   (343b531d31eeb933ec778dbcf7081628a1396067),platform=Windows NT 10.0
>   x86_64)

I have tried to select/ click the item, but the error repeats, that the element could not me found.

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseUrl + TextTranslate);
driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("translateSystemContainer")).Click();
new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("options"))).SelectByText(sysID);
```

Comment: have you tried clicking on the drop down first and then using the code for selection?

Comment: Yes i have tried many variants to get somekinde of response. The error still thesame , that the element could not be found the test fails.

 driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseUrl + TextTranslate);
            driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("translateSystemContainer")).Click();
            new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("options"))).SelectByText(sysID);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("options"))).SelectByText(sysID);
```

Here you are trying to find the element where `class="options"`, which is a `<ul>`. You can't 'select' a UL. You can select if it's a  list.

Also, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471515/webdriver-c-sharp-select-a-value-from-drop-down) out.